# android sync sqlite with Parse.com

Tags: android, database, sqlite, synchronization, parse-platform

hello guys I need your help to solve this issua that I have.
Some guy told me that sync sqlite (DB local in my android device) can sync with the DB of parse.com how it is posible= I mean if its necesary to copy all my DB from Parse.com and paste to my local sqlite DB but Im sure that is not the best way.

For example if I change some data from parse.com DB, this change will update automatically the sqlite DB of my device when I have internet connection.
¿what is the best way to sync this?
pls if you can give me some examples, advices,etc I will apreciate.
greetings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know the question is outdated, but I's like to share my solution to this problem.

I've created a simple and easy to use library, that enables you to synchronise data between local SQLite database and Parse.com. Here is its GitHub repo: [ParseDataSync for Android](https://github.com/ntoskrnl/DataSync)

Synchronization relies on `syncId`, `syncDate` fields and `deleted` flag, suggested in the [discussion at parse.com](https://parse.com/questions/how-to-synchronize-between-local-db-sqlite-and-parse). Because it relies on date, it will not work if the time on the device is incorrect (or differs from the parse.com server). So, you have to resolve this kind of situation yourself.

The library provides annotations to map your OrmLite entity classes to Parse classes. It is currently a preview, but I am planning to make it more stable and functional.

Leave a comment or create an issue on GitHub. I would really appreciate your feedback.

Comment: ok I will check cz im still doing some work and i really need to use parse.com in a few days I will check the answer thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This question was asked on the [forums over at Parse](https://parse.com/questions/how-to-synchronize-between-local-db-sqlite-and-parse).

The end result: it is a matter of doing it manually.

From my experience in sync, I would suggest you handle Inserts, then Updates, then Deletes, look for conflicts, and keep track of something to know where you are up to (date/time works, but has issues).

Handling deletes on the client and the server will mean either doing soft deletes (boolean IsDeleted flag) or having a tombstone table, or some other way to track them. For the server you can add Cloud Code that runs on/before delete. Client side you'll need to change the code that can execute a delete on the local db.

Doing server-first or client-first will depend on what sort of conflicts you expect and how you want to resolve them.